# Python3 - print string and list

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to write the code below shorter, on one line?

```
print("Start line ", end="")
print(*list, sep=", ", end="")
print(" end of line.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using a single `print` call, with the help of `join`:

```
list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
print("Start line [" + ", ".join(list) + "] end of line.", end="")

Start line [one, two, three] end of line.
```

Answer (score 0):

Might it makes a little bit more shorter.

```
print(f'Start Line {lst} End of line')
```